# How numpy.loadtxt loads files via slicing

Tags: numpy

If I use the following to slice from a file:

`np.loadtxt(filename)[0:3]`

Does it guarantee that it ONLY loads **the slicing portion**? I am afraid it loads the entire file first into the memory followed by slicing `[1:3]` which is undesirable to me as I will be having very large files to load in the future.

Comment: The `loadtxt` executes first, producing an array.  The slicing occurs after load.  Also slicing like that creates a `view`.  The original data is still present in memory.  `np.genfromtxt` lets you specify a `max_rows`.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you very much. `np.genfromtxt ` does not allow me to load specific range? Say from line 30 to line 50. Is that correct?

Comment: WIth a combination of `skip_rows` and `max_rows` you should be able to control the load range.  The other option is to load those lines yourself, and pass that list of lines to `loadtxt`.  Those functions work with anything that gives them a list or generator of lines.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you. Do you think using `np.genfromtxt` is more efficient? I will be dealing with large files in gigabytes so performance is very important with me

Comment: `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` do basically the same thing - read a file line by line, parse it, collect values in a list of lists, and create an array at the end.  `pandas` has a faster compiled csv reader.